# Automatic addition of brackets/parentheses in table

Tags: tables, siunitx

I have the following table;

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\scriptsize
 \sisetup{round-mode=places}

\begin{tabular}{lS[round-precision=2]
            S[round-precision=2]S[round-precision=2]S[round-precision=2]S[round-precision=2]
            S[round-precision=2]S[round-precision=2]S[round-precision=2]
            S[round-precision=2]S[round-precision=2]S[round-precision=2]S[round-precision=2]
            S[round-precision=2]S[round-precision=2]} \hline \hline
  \\  \hline 
ZR & [-23.0457 & 29.572025] & -10.765862 & 12.058692 & -11.031138 & 11.065893 & -28.195796 & 28.162882 & -39.643381 & 39.66185 & -10.765862 & 11.065893 & -22.074058 & 23.699934 \\  
OP & -22.726045 & .31390256 & -9.1251163 & 2.1487149 & -6.7200799 & 9.546617 & -15.378546 & 27.88493 & -21.525421 & 39.567726 & -6.7200799 & .31390256 & -14.935931 & 15.236132 \\  
IS & -4.7930777 & 3.9469064 & -4.7311899 & 3.7447689 & -2.5053514 & 2.2386198 & -.45707635 & .38682361 & -.44266571 & .44049075 & -.44266571 & .38682361 & -2.6230893 & 2.1830086 \\  
\hline \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Each odd (even) column corresponds to the lower (upper) bound of an interval; Is there a way of adding square brackets [ ] to the left (right) of each numbers without having to do that manually (as shown in the first two values in the first row)? I'm going nuts searching for an answer...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch: thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For this output

[image: w]

use

```
\begin{tabular}{l
        >{[}S[round-precision=2]
        S[round-precision=2]<{]}
```

...

the `>{[}`  inserts `[` before the the column, `<{]}` does it after.

Or use

```
\begin{tabular}{l
        >{[}S[table-format=4.2]@{}
        S[table-format=3.2]<{]}
```

to align the brackets and a more compact output. `@{}` removes inter column space.

[image: a]

Finally you could expand the cells vertically with `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<factor>}`

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}        
    
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}% expand the cells
    \scriptsize
    \sisetup{round-mode=places} 
    \begin{tabular}{l *{7}{>{[}S[table-format=4.2]@{}S[table-format=3.2]<{]} }                  }                   
        \hline \hline
        \\  \hline 
        ZR & -23.0457   & 29.57202  & -10.765862 & 12.058692 & -11.031138 & 11.065893 & -28.195796 & 28.162882 & -39.643381 & 39.66185 & -10.765862 & 11.065893 & -22.074058 & 23.699934 \\  
        OP & -22.726045 & .31390256 & -9.1251163 & 2.1487149 & -6.7200799 & 9.546617 & -15.378546 & 27.88493 & -21.525421 & 39.567726 & -6.7200799 & .31390256 & -14.935931 & 15.236132 \\  
        IS & -4.7930777 & 3.9469064 & -4.7311899 & 3.7447689 & -2.5053514 & 2.2386198 & -.45707635 & .38682361 & -.44266571 & .44049075 & -.44266571 & .38682361 & -2.6230893 & 2.1830086 \\  
        \hline \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{table} 
    
\end{document
```

`*{7}{<column(s) format>}` repeats the column(s) format 7 times.

Comment: Thanks Simon; works like clockwork and I've learned something useful. Extreme gratitude!